# Is there a way to override a specific keyword color in VS CODE theme (Material Theme)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to override specific keywords (import, export, try, catch, await, return etc) of a VS Code "Material Theme"... There's a way to overwrite all the keywords like so

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Material Theme Darker]": {
        "keywords": "#1ed680"
    }
},
```

But this overwrites every keyword, and I just need those of a specific blue color... Is there any way to do so? VS Code documentation didn't specify it for certain keywords/tokens
[image]

But obviously there's a way to do it... Thanks a lot

Comment: What makes it obvious that this is possible?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn cause you can create your own theme

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+P` -> `Inspect TM scopes`, click on the keyword and figure out the full name for it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ok, thanks! I figured, it's "keyword.control". And where do I go from there? How to target it in settings.json?

Comment: `"editor.tokenColorCustomizations":{"keyword.control": "$FF9900"}`, I guess?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat doesn't work unfortunately, says "keyword.control property not allowed"

Comment: You want that in `textMateRules`.